# How to make a CSD call from modem

Tags: gsm, at-command, modem

I recently bought a modem that supports CSD (Circuit Switched Data) calls. I put SIM card in it and I am able to make calls via AT commands. But these are always VOICE calls. I have another modem and I need to connect to it via CSD.

I know it is possible because our colleagues are using it this way to access some network.

They are using windows dial-up connection, but I guess that is just something that in the background calls the AT commands.

Nevertheless the dial-up is still giving me "Error 678: Remote computer did not respond". I have tried many settings, but still the same error. I even tried different computer and still got the same error.

So I found out that when I call CSD, then on the receiving side (if `AT+CRC=1`) it should display `+CRING: REL ASYNC`. So I setup another modem and called it and it showed `+CRING: VOICE`.

So how do I convince my modem to call in the REL ASYNC mode?
I already tried:

```
AT+IPR=115200 or AT+IPR=9600
AT+FCLASS=0 (this is default though)
AT+CSNS=4
AT+CBST=7,0,0 or AT+CBST=71,0,1
AT^SXRAT=0 (this changes the network to GSM)
```

But still when I do `ATDNUMBERIWANTTOCALL;` the receiving side shows `+CRING: VOICE`.

Also my mobile provider ensured me, that the CSD technology is still supported in my country and that I do not need any kind of special SIM card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the number could be called normally like it is written in the question, but it only worked in Germany, not abroad...

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the semicolon after the phone number in the ATD command: that semicolon is what tells the modem to make a voice call rather than CSD.

Comment: that is true, but still it was not working for me. In the end I discovered that it did not work in my country (Czech Republic) when trying to connect to a modem in Germany. Even when I tried SIM card that worked in Germany for this, it did not work in Czech Republic, so probably CSD is not supported in my country.

Answer (score 0):

Check with your teleoperator does your sim card have separate data number.

Sometimes postpaid (and/or M2M) cards have three different numbers
1. voice
2. fax
3. data

Comment: I also asked about this, I was told that no, only one number. Even when it would have, it is me who is calling, so even if I had separate number for data calls, I guess the modem would handle it. I even went to Germany (where my colleagues are using CSD to connect to a network) to test it and even bought prepaid card there but it didn't help. I guess they have some sort of special SIM card (M2M) or something. They are telling me it is normal SIM card, but maybe they do not know that it is not.